# MEAN Stack - MongoDB - Looping through documents with two different conditions

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I am creating MEAN Stack application for doctor and in MongoDB I have different collections (Users and Patients) - see attached images for better understanding of how it looks.

[image]
[image]

I created the functionality where every user can login and logout with their email and password, and when logged in he can only see, edit and delete the patients he has added, and not the other patients (from other doctors).

When doctor add new patient, in MongoDB patient is saved with doctor ID (please see image below), so when that user is logged in, I loop through patients and display only patients for that doctor

I have an issue when I want to display message "Niste dodali pacijente..." (You don't have patients yet...) when the logged in user does't have any patients, or delete their previous patients...

I tried with :

```
 <p class="text-center" *ngIf="patient.length == 0 || userIsAuthenticated && (userId === patient.doctor) == 0">Niste dodali pacijente...</p>
```

and when Doctor 4 logged in, he gets this (his patients and messages that the previous doctor does not have patients)

[image]

the same situation for other doctors (Doctor 3 for example)

[image]

Please help me how to fix this issue, practically I want to display message "Niste dodali pacijente" just if that doctor delete all patients or if he does not add patients yet. Thank you

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let patient of patients">
       <!-- Patient accordion -->
        <accordion [closeOthers]="onePatientAtTime" ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && userId === patient.doctor">
             ...
        </accordion>
        <p class="text-center" *ngIf="patient.length == 0 || userIsAuthenticated && (userId === patient.doctor) == 0">Niste dodali pacijente...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to  Stackoverflow? Please avoid images where possible. The first two should be replaced with json snippets with examples of the documents. Add relevant code where you query the database to retrieve the list you are trying to display.

Comment: Could you please share your API response.

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate since you are looping through the patients list you should probably use a boolean variable to trigger this case.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div *ngIf="shouldNoPatientsShow" class="col-12" *ngFor="let patient of patients">
       <!-- Patient accordion -->
        <accordion [closeOthers]="onePatientAtTime" ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && userId === patient.doctor">
             ...
        </accordion>
    </div>
        <p class="text-center" *ngIf="shouldNoPatientsShow || userIsAuthenticated && (userId === patient.doctor) == 0">Niste dodali pacijente...</p>
</div>
```

and in ts file set the variable shouldNoPatient show to true if the array of patients is 0

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, I changed the logic, and now every patient will be visible to any doctor, but only doctor who added patient can edit and or delete that patient...

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
       <!-- Patient accordion -->
        <accordion [closeOthers]="onePatientAtTime" *ngIf="patients.length > 0">
            <accordion-group #group class="mb-3" *ngFor="let patient of patients">
                ...
                <div class="edit-form-buttons text-right" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && userId === patient.doctor">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mr-2" [routerLink]="['/izmjena-pacijenta', patient.id]">Izmijeni</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(patient.id)">Izbriši</button>
                </div>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
        <p class="text-center" *ngIf="patients.length <= 0">Niste dodali pacijente...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```